# Product of a derivative and a continuous function is a Darboux function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval. Suppose that $f(x)$ has an antiderivative on $I$ and $g(x)$ is continuous on $I$, I have to prove that $f(x)g(x)$ is a Darboux function, having the intermediate value property.

($f(x)$ is said to have the intermediate value property on $I$, if for every $a,b\in I$, $a<b$, and $r\in [f(a),f(b)]$ (or $[f(b),f(a)]$), there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = r$.)

If $f$ is nonzero everywhere, we actually know that $fg$ has an antiderivative (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277260/does-the-product-fg-have-antiderivative)). The same applies if $f$ is bounded above of below (even just locally) since we can add a constant to $f$. But in general, $fg$ may not have an antiderivative. An example can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439669/prove-or-disprove-the-product-of-two-functions-has-antiderivatives-if-one-of-th).

I have no idea what to do with this problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for having to delete my answer, which contained a few mistakes. By the way, are you told in advance that what you're trying to prove is indeed correct? that there is no counterexample?

Comment: There are many questions of this type discussed in this Monthly paper:  *Some Aspects of Products of Derivatives*,  A. M. Bruckner, J. Marik and C. E. Weil, The American Mathematical Monthly , Feb., 1992, Vol. 99, No. 2 (Feb., 1992), pp. 134-145.  I can't see this particular problem there but some of the ideas there might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some background source for this problem.  Not a solution (alas) but you could use this material to find the neatest one.

First: it is *true* that the product of a derivative and a continuous function must be a Darboux function.  More precisely that product is a Darboux Baire 1 function.  As the OP notes the product of a derivative and a continuous function need not, however, be a derivative.  If it were then this would be obvious (it isn't).

The first person to ask such questions seems to have been Isaiah Maximoff in the 1930s.

He proved this:

> If $f$ is a real-valued function on $R$ then $f$ is a Darboux function
> of the first Baire class if and only if there is a homeomorphism $h$
> of $R$ onto $R$ such that $f∘h$ is a derivative.

In a series of papers (some listed below) he gave several characterizations of the class of Baire 1 Darboux functions.  From those you can deduce this:

**Theorem.**  *The sum and the product of a Darboux function in Baire class 1 and a continuous function  are also Darboux functions in Baire class 1.*

It can be deduced in a different way too (can't everything?).  Bruckner, Ceder and Weiss in reference [1] explored this problem:

> Every real-valued function can be expressed as the pointwise limit of
> a sequence of Darboux functions.  Characterize those functions which
> can be expessed as the *uniform* limit of a sequence of Darboux
> functions.

Their solution of this problem also can be applied here.  As they stated in the paper:

> It follows from Theorem 4.4 and the corollary that the sum and
> product of a Darboux function in Baire class 1 and a continuous
> function  are also Darboux functions in Baire class 1.   This also
> follows from a criterion of Maximoff ([2], p. 260).

**Acknowledgement.**  My thanks to Andy Bruckner for pointing to his 1966 paper with Jack Ceder and Max Weiss for background on this problem.

**REFERENCES:**

[1]  Bruckner, A. M.; Ceder, J. G.; Weiss, Max.
Uniform limits of Darboux functions.
Colloq. Math. 15 (1966), 65–77.

[2] Maximoff, Isaiah.  Sur les fonctions ayant la propriété de Darboux. Prace Matematyczno-Fizyczne 43 (1936), 241-265.

[3] Maximoff, Isaiah. On approximately continuous functions. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (1939), 264-268.

[4] Maximoff, Isaiah.
On functions of class 1 having the property of Darboux.
Amer. J. Math. 65 (1943), 161–170.

---

*Postscript.*  Maximoff has 18 publications listed from 1939-1944.  The only indications of where he was is  "TCHEBOLSSARY, TCHAPAEWSKIPOSELOK, U.S.S.R."  I can't find any biographical detail about him.  Those dates and his presence in the soviet union in those years suggests a sad story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very enlightening indeed. About the theorem given, I believe that the product of **a Darboux function** and **a continuous function** may not be Darboux, am I right?

Comment: @JianingSong  You are right.  The assumption that the Darboux function is Baire 1 plays a role.

Comment: Thank you very much!